# Nuxt - cookies are not sent in request

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt for the frontend of an application that uses Django on the backend, and Django uses the standard Session Auth.

I'm trying to create a middleware that checks if the user is logged in before loading the page, but the problem is that i keep getting redirected to the login page even when i'm logged in. I made some checks and found that Django is not receiving any cookie from the middleware.

Here is the middleware:

```
export default function (context) {
  return axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkAuth',
        withCredentials: true,
      }).then(function (response) {
        //handle success, redirect if not logged in...
      }).catch(function (error) {
        //handle error
      });
}
```

This same code seems to work (the cookie is sent) from a simple Nuxt page instead. Am i doing something wrong here? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the axios value? please check your browser console and/or show me the console print out.

Comment: Yeah i made sure that the request is sent. Also i made my backend print the request, and i noticed that when the request comes from the middleware there aren't cookies in the request. When the request is sent from a simple Nuxt page the cookies are there, this is very weird